# Ranorex: How to stop testcase if exception occurs?

Tags: c#, winforms, ranorex

I'm using Ranorex for Testautomation. I built a Testcase and it runs as expected. But if a unhandled exception occurs the Testcase isnt stopping. How is it possible to stop my Test if an `Exception` occurs? I dont mean a `RanorexException`. It's an Exception which occurs on my Program. All documentation I found so far tell me to track the `ErrorBox` and validate this. But it could be any error and i dont know how the `ErrorDialog` is looking. I need something which identify any type of `Exception`, so that iam able to log an error.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.  Is it your Ranorex test program that gets an Exception or is it your program?  If it is inside your Ranorex test program, simply catching Exception instead of RanorexException will do the trick.  If it is an exception in your Program, you will need to find a way to verify if the Exception occurred or not, such as the presence of popup window for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you implement some good validations in your test cases. for example when you add something in a list of a form, open and close the form again and validate if it is added. if an exception occurs it won't find the added value and the test case fails. Ranorex will then make a screenshot in the report and you'll see the exception.

If the exception info is not visible rerun the test case while you're watching.

You can also run Debugview in background while running Ranorex

Comment: @user52986275 ah ok. Thank you. I hoped that Ranorex can identify if an exception is thrown.